# Getting the property expression from a property model in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I've got a form on the page whose model is a `CompoundPropertyModel`. I've got a bunch of children on this form.

My goal is to create a behaviour, which could determine what property expression the object the behavior is being attached to has (or if it has a non-property expression throw an exception).

I'm trying to do this in the [`bind`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/behavior/Behavior.html#bind%28org.apache.wicket.Component%29) method so that in case it cannot be configured I would catch this early.

I got as far as extracting the model from the component. I was about to do an `instanceof` when I realised that the model retrieved could not necessarily be an `AbstractPropertyModel` as I've been expecting, since I am doing this using a `CompountPropertyModel`.

So my question is: is there a reliable way I can find the property expression of a given model without knowing the model's type, but knowing it is a property model? (When I say 'a property model' I mean any model that is based on a property expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wicket 'knowing it is a property model' means it's an `AbstractPropertyModel` - thus your `instanceof` check should work fine.

If you rely on `CompoundPropertyModel` implicitly initialising your model, then it will still be an `AbstractPropertyModel`. Make sure that you have added the component to the parent providing the `CompoundPropertyModel` before querying for the model though.

Comment: When I say 'knowing it is a property model' I also include the possibility that the model of an object can be implicit, derived from the parent's CompoundPropertyModel, for example. Is the model that gets derived from the CompoundPropertyModel also an AbstractPropertyModel?

Comment: I found that the answer to the question I posted above is true. If you don't mind, I will amend your answer to include that specific case.